# How to pass included vars into method?

Tags: php, oop, var

```
include_once('vars.php'); //contains $login and $password

echo $login.' '.$password; //returns $login and $password correct
$session = new SomeObject();
$session->login($login, $password); //returns false
```

SomeObject is incapsulated cause I don't have access to it.
How to pass included vars into method to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in there

```
$session->login($login, $password); //returns false
```

You wrote $pasword (only one s)

Comment: Then you either need access to SomeObject if you think its implementation is wrong, or the credentials you present are wrong.